# How to use UNIX sockets in .htaccess RewriteRule?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, unix-socket

I'd like to proxy some requests on OS X machine from Apache server using configuration in `.htaccess` file to Node.js app listening on a UNIX socket. I'll use it in a development environment not production if this clarification is necessary.

The problem is that I'm not sure how to write the `RewriteRule` for it or even if this is possible.

Current `.htaccess` file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle WebSockets
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/socket.io
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ unix:/Users/xxx/xxx/nodejs.sock [P,L]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

There is a node.js app listening on that UNIX socket, I can see the file `/Users/xxx/xxx/nodejs.sock=` from terminal (`=` sign is just supposed to indicate that it's a UNIX socket I think?). When visiting the path `/socket.io` from browser, I still see `index.php` file executed.

I assume that the problem must be in the format of UNIX socket.